# How to pass XML data as a parameter to a TVP param from C# to Sql server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml, table-valued-parameters

I want to pass a paramter of type XML to a param in a TVP. I tried the below code, which does not work. I am unable to figure out if there is a way to pass an xml data to a TVP in sql server.

**sql**

```
CREATE TABLE XmlSample(Id INT,  Profile XML);

CREATE TYPE [SampleProfile_DataTYPE] AS TABLE 
     (      
        Id INT, 
        Profile XML
      );

CREATE PROCEDURE XmlTvpSprocTest_Save
@SamplesTvp [SampleProfile_DataTYPE] READONLY
AS  
BEGIN  
  INSERT INTO XmlSample (Id, Profile)
  SELECT DeviceID, Profile
  FROM @SamplesTvp 
END
```

Applicatin side code in C#

```
public void SaveXmlTestData()
        {
            string xdata = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""ISO - 8859 - 1""?><note><to>Rahul</to></note>";
            var samples= GetSamplesTvp(1, 1, XElement.Parse(xdata));
            using (DbCommand cmd = database.GetStoredProcCommand("XmlTvpSprocTest_Save"))
            {
                var param = new SqlParameter("@SamplesTvp ", samples) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                database.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
            }
        }

private DataTable GetSamplesTvp(int deviceId, XmlDocument xmldata)
        {
            var table= new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Profile", typeof(XElement));
            table.Rows.Add(deviceId, xmldata);
            return table;
        }
```

I get the exception **The type of column is not supported**.
The xml parameter has to be included in a TVP (Profile) along with other parameters. part of the reason is that, I will have to save a list of xml profiles along with their corresponding Ids, did someone come across anything similar?

Answer (score 0):

passing the data as `string` actually worked

```
 public void SaveXmlTestData_WithString()
        {
            //<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC"">
            string xdata = @"<note><to>profile</to></note>";
            var samples= GetSamplesTvp(1, xdata);
            using (DbCommand cmd = database.GetStoredProcCommand("XmlTvpSprocTest"))
            {
                var param1 = new SqlParameter("@SamplesTvp ", samples) { SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured };
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);
                database.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
            }
        }

private List<SqlDataRecord> GetSamplesTvp(int Id, string xmldata)
        {
            List<SqlDataRecord> tvprecord = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
            var column1 = new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.Int);
            var column2 = new SqlMetaData("Profiles", SqlDbType.Xml);
            var data = new SqlMetaData[] { column1, column2 };
            var sqlrecord = new SqlDataRecord(data);
            sqlrecord.SetValue(0, Id);
            sqlrecord.SetValue(1, xmldata);
            tvprecord.Add(sqlrecord);
            return tvprecord;
        }
```

Although, I do get an exception if I add the commented out xml to the xmlData 
`(Name cannot start with '.' character)` That's another issue but the core of the problem got solved by simply passing the param as string from c# and keeping the tvp param in sql as Xml